# Xojo says "Build Failed" and dies without further message

Tags: xojo

I am trying to Run a project in Xojo, which used to run okay previously.

Currently observed behavior:

- Clicking "Run", has Xojo display various messages, including "Done Assembling Code".
- Then, "Build Failed" dialog box flashes briefly.  So briefly, I cannot even grab a screenshot.
- And then it disappears, and no diagnostic error/warning messages are given.

I am new to Xojo.  The project used to build okay.  Something must have changed.  Is there a way to somehow see what the problem is?  Right now it looks like the IDE keeps on working but the Run process just dies, after barely flashing "Build Failed" Dialog Box.

I will consider it a successful answer if it helps or aids me in the direction of solving this issue.

Comment: I've never seen that happen on Mac OS X. Please specify which system you're using. Also clarify the the IDE quits or not. Are there crash reports for the IDE if it crashes?

Comment: It's windows server 2012.  IDE does not quit.  Where can I find crash reports?

Comment: Turns out the Debug folder was locked by another process.  Releasing the lock, restored Run operation.

Comment: No idea where Windows puts crash reports. I'd google it :) Glad to see you've solved it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the Debug folder was locked by another process.  Releasing the lock, restored Run operation.

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I find crash reports?

Windows allows you to collect a *Minidump* when a crash occurs.

The procedure requires modifying a registry value using Regedit. You can also do so with the Xojo command Registry http://docs.xojo.com/index.php/Registry

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for the exact procedure.